# Facebook audience network ad status stuck on requesting ads

Tags: android, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

i am using Facebook audience network I've created an Android app and integrated native and interstitial ads ... Now the problem is that placement status is on requesting ads for both native and interstitial but fill rate and impressions are null what am i missing ...
My app is live please help

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet! still waiting for someone to respond

Comment: Did you try creating a new ad space?

Comment: Yes i have created multiple new ad spaces

Comment: Did you find any success, I am facing similar problem

Comment: @Tabish any progress on this issue?

Comment: @SAHM no sir not at this point, i'll try making a new account and try again sometime

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the ad unit code given to you by Facebook Inc. when you're deployig it for the first time you're deploying on the real application/project that you're going to publish to the PlayStore.You'll notice that Facebook doesn't give test ads unit code like Google does.If you deploy that ad unit code on another project and use the same unit code on another project it'll not show the live ads on two projects differently.So don't use the live ads unit code to the several test projects you'll be working on them but on the real project you'll publish.
Hopefully that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by just update SDK,
So Use the latest version of the SDK from Facebook for the Developers' site.